# AJV schema validation fails

Tags: node.js, node-modules, ajv, jsonix

I am using Jsonix, I have used below mentioned command to generate jsonix mapping and jsonix schema as,

```
java -jar jsonix-schema-compiler-full.jar -generateJsonSchema -d mappings books.xsd
```

it is properly generating mapping and schema, I want to validate JSON using **AJV** and the generated JSON Schema, so I have tried this,

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Ajv = require('ajv');

var XMLSchemaJsonSchema = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('../node_modules/jsonix/jsonschemas/w3c/2001/XMLSchema.jsonschema').toString());
var JsonixJsonSchema = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('../node_modules/jsonix/jsonschemas/jsonix/Jsonix.jsonschema').toString());
var booksJsonSchema = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./books.jsonschema').toString());

var ajv = new Ajv();
ajv.addSchema(XMLSchemaJsonSchema, 'http://www.jsonix.org/jsonschemas/w3c/2001/XMLSchema.jsonschema');
ajv.addSchema(JsonixJsonSchema, 'http://www.jsonix.org/jsonschemas/jsonix/Jsonix.jsonschema');
var validate = ajv.compile(booksJsonSchema);

var data ={
   "book": [
      {
         "@id": "bk001",
         "author": "Writer",
         "title": "The First Book",
         "genre": "Fiction",
         "price": "44.95",
         "pub_date":2000-10-01,
         "review": "An amazing story of nothing."
      },
      {
         "@id": "bk002",
         "author": "Poet",
         "title": "The Poet's First Poem",
         "genre": "Poem",
         "price": "24.95",
         "pub_date":2000-10-02,
         "review": "Least poetic poems."
      }
   ]
};

var valid = validate(data);
if (!valid) {
    console.log('Validation failed errors:');
    console.log(validate.errors);
}else{
    console.log("successfully done validation");
}
```

But it is throwing error

```
/Users/qliktag/Desktop/QAGG/qagUI2/Scripts/QLIKTAG-2602/node_modules/ajv/lib/ajv.js:183
    else throw new Error(message);
               ^
Error: schema is invalid: data.definitions['nonPositiveInteger'].anyOf[0].exclusiveMaximum should be number
    at Ajv.validateSchema (/Users/qliktag/Desktop/QAGG/qagUI2/testScripts/node_modules/ajv/lib/ajv.js:185:16)
    at Ajv._addSchema (/Users/qliktag/Desktop/QAGG/qagUI2/Scripts/QLIKTAG-2602/node_modules/ajv/lib/ajv.js:316:10)
    at Ajv.addSchema (/Users/qliktag/Desktop/QAGG/qagUI2/Scripts/QLIKTAG-2602/node_modules/ajv/lib/ajv.js:136:29)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/qliktag/Desktop/QAGG/qagUI2/Scripts/QLIKTAG-2602/mappings/ajvSample.js:248:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
```

Actually the error comes while ajv addschema, Is I did anything wrong?

Comment: According to JSON Scheme, `exclusiveMaximum` must be a number. But in the `www.jsonix.org/jsonschemas/w3c/2001/XMLSchema.jsonschema` the `exclusiveMaximum` is false and ajv is throwing.

Comment: https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/blob/master/schema.json and you can see `"exclusiveMaximum": {
            "type": "number"
},`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To continue using **draft-04 schemas** added `meta: false` **to prevent adding draft-06 meta-schema** https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/releases/tag/5.0.0

```
var ajv = new Ajv({
    schemaId: 'id',
    meta: false, 
});

var metaSchema = require('../node_modules/ajv/lib/refs/json-schema-draft-04.json');
ajv.addMetaSchema(metaSchema);
ajv._opts.defaultMeta = metaSchema.id;
ajv._refs['http://json-schema.org/schema'] = 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema';
```

After adding this use **addSchema** to allow booleans for exclusiveMaximum

```
ajv.addSchema(XMLSchemaJsonSchema, 'http://www.jsonix.org/jsonschemas/w3c/2001/XMLSchema.jsonschema');
ajv.addSchema(JsonixJsonSchema, 'http://www.jsonix.org/jsonschemas/jsonix/Jsonix.jsonschema');
```

Answer (score 0):

The change of `exclusiveMaximum` from boolean to number happened with Draft-06/07 of JSON Schema.

```
// var ajv = new Ajv({schemaId: 'id'});
// If you want to use both draft-04 and draft-06/07 schemas:
var ajv = new Ajv({schemaId: 'auto'});
ajv.addMetaSchema(require('ajv/lib/refs/json-schema-draft-04.json'));
```

Use this and then `addSchema` to allow booleans for `exclusiveMaximum`

```
ajv.addSchema(XMLSchemaJsonSchema, 'http://www.jsonix.org/jsonschemas/w3c/2001/XMLSchema.jsonschema');
ajv.addSchema(JsonixJsonSchema, 'http://www.jsonix.org/jsonschemas/jsonix/Jsonix.jsonschema');
```

Comment: I have tried the changes you suggested but still it is throwing the error the same error which i mentioned above as "exclusiveMaximum should be number". Is there any other change I have to do.

Comment: Which version of `ajv` do you have?

Comment: I am using ajv@6.1.1 version

Comment: ajv@6 should support changing schema: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv

Comment: One more thing on terminal it is showing "schema $id ignored http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema# " what does it means exactly?

Comment: I think the draft-04 schema did not load properly

Comment: I again uninstall and install the ajv npm module but still showing same error

Comment: Let's try the `{schemaId: 'auto'}`

Answer (score 0):

Author of Jsonix here.

As it is pointed out in the [documentation](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix-schema-compiler/wiki/JSON-Schema-Generation), JSON Schema generation is an experimental feature. So it would be not surprizing that it fails. You are welcome to [file issues](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix-schema-compiler/issues).